# Get list of all publishing pages checked out

Tags: publishing-site, check-out

For a specific SharePoint 2010 web site, is there a way to get a list of all publishing pages (Pages library) items that are checked out regardless of how many subfolders deep they are located? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to use this query:

```
SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
q.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\""
q.Query = "<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='int'>0</Value></Geq></Where>";
var pages = pagesList.GetItems(q);
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. A silly follow-up: Is this a PowerShell script or server-side ASP.NET code? And can this be done in a way such that we can check in the checked out pages? Thanks.

Comment: this is a server side code.. but I do not see any reason why do you not to use this solution is PowerShell. I think that checked in files has null value in this filed, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks. Would this code go into an application page?

Comment: Why not? This code should work anyway when you have access to the SharePoint object model :)

Comment: What you get back using this method is the SPListItem for each page. For each of these you can get the listitem.File object and call CheckIn and Publish on that.<br />The code can go into a application page, console app, web part, ... what ever you want or be rewritten to PowerShell syntax

Answer (score 4):

Another, non code way to get a list of all checked out items, is the following. This is a neat small tool for your content editors, too.

1. go to http://website/Reports%20List/AllItems.aspx
2. Add new item. At the same query as above (0)
3. go to the sitemanager http:///_layouts/sitemanager.aspx
4. Select your library with publishing pages in it.
5. Select in "View" the name of the query that you added:

[image: reports]
[image: view with checked out items]

Comment: Didn't know you could do that! Thanks, Bas Lijten! Just tried it and worked beautifully :)

Comment: a lot of people don't know about it ;). It's one of those gems that I love! A custom view on a lib would have worked too, btw.

Answer (score 1):

In a publishing site you can use Manage Content and Structure and under view change it to "All Draft documents"

(Site actions > Manage Content Structure)

[image: View]