# Comprehensive list of pages checked out

Tags: sharepoint-online

I read this: [Get list of all publishing pages checked out](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33057/get-list-of-all-publishing-pages-checked-out)

But I don't have access to the server side scripting (accepted answer).

I followed Bas' suggestion for adding a new report but

1. How do I add a column to that report which will show me the user to which a page is checked out?
2. How do I get the report to show all pages from all subsites? (As an aside, the third answer mentions the report "All Draft Documents" and the SP description of this report says "All documents and pages not yet published in this site and subsites" but my experience is that subsites are not reported by this report either)